# Exporting aws management console settings

Tags: amazon-web-services

When using the `aws web management console` it's very handy to add favourite services and switch between different roles. However when using a different browser or different computer with the same login it's not showing up.

How to export these settings so they can be imported or synced between computers?

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to things like 'favourite' services at the top of the screen and Switch Role settings, they are stored in cookies on your local computer.

You could possibly synchronize cookies between computers using a browser plugin, but the AWS Management Console won't do it for you.

Comment: Thanks, I've looked at the `noflush_awsc-roleInfo` and `noflush_awscnm` cookies, but it's hard to find any more info about how this works

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is not natively supported by AWS. I use [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) for a similar need. It also has Chrome extension.

Answer (score 0):

That is not supported my AWS Management Console